# How to set different source directories in cedet?

Tags: cedet, emacs24

How do I specify different source directories under cedet ?

I have configured my project like this:

```
(when (file-exists-p "~/ws/madwifi/build/Makefile")  
(setq cpp-tests-project  
(ede-cpp-root-project "madwifi"  
                  :file "~/ws/madwifi/build/Makefile"  
                  :system-include-path '("~/ws/madwifi/build/include/drivers"  
                                         "~/ws/madwifi/build/include/hw/"  
                                         )  
)))
```

But when I do a semantic-symref-symbol on a symbol, it sometimes lists only functions
that are used in the project. variables are not symref'd
But when I completely remove the block above, it shows the references of variables only 
from the current directory. How to properly configure ede-cpp-root-project.

Answer (score 1):

The symref tools only work within the current project, and do not pull data in from include paths.  You can search for references to a symbol from an include file, but it won't find the declaration from the includes.

The symref tool works with several different external tools such as GNU Global or idutils.  In theory you could use one of those tools to index whichever files you want, and as long as the index file is at the root of your project, it will find it, and also find your external includes.  I haven't tried this though, so I don't know if these tools have that capability.

If you want to jump to a reference in an external include, you can use other tools, like semantic-ia-fast-jump and that uses include paths instead of project indicies, but it won't find references.